# how does __contains__ method work in binary search trees Python?

Tags: python, binary-search-tree, contains

I have two classes, Node() and binarySearchTree().
Node() has the attributes:

```
    self.left= None
    self.right= None
    self.key= key
    self.data = data
```

And binarySearchTree() has methods for inserting, searching and printing the binary search tree (BST). I must also include a `__contains__` method for my BST, which enables me to write something like:

```
tree= Bintree()
tree.store("table")
 
if "table" in tree:  <--
    do something     <--
```

It complains about the last two "`__contains__`" that they're not defined. But I'd like it to work recursively. But it's not working.

```
    def __contains__(self, key):
        if self.root == None:
            return False
        elif key== self.root.key:
            return True
        elif key < self.root.key:
            return __contains__(self.root.key.left,key)
        elif key > self.root.key:
            return __contains__(self.root.key.right,key)
```

Comment: You need `self.` in front of the method name.

Comment: Or just use `in` instead of calling `__contains__` directly: `key in self.root.left`.

Comment: What exactly is `self.root`? Does *it* have `left` and `right` attributes, or does `self` itself have those attributes?

Answer (score 1):

`__contains__` is not a global variable; it's a class attribute, and so must be accessed via `BinTree` or one of its instances. At the very least, you need to write

```
def __contains__(self, key):
    if self.root == None:
        return False
    elif key == self.root.key:
        return True
    elif key < self.root.key:
        return BinTree.__contains__(self.root.left, key)
    elif key > self.root.key:
        return BinTree.__contains__(self.root.right, key)
```

(Note that the `key` attribute isn't needed in the first argument; it's `self.root` itself, not its key, that has `left` and `right` attributes.

However, this is just a non-standard way of calling an instance attribute that prevents inherited from working correctly. It will also fail if you change the name of the class without updating the definition of the method to use the new name. The next best thing would be to invoke the method normally.

```
def __contains__(self, key):
    if self.root == None:
        return False
    elif key == self.root.key:
        return True
    elif key < self.root.key:
        return self.root.left.__contains__(key)
    elif key > self.root.key:
        return self.root.right.__contains__(key)
```

But best of all is to not call `__contains__` directly, but use to use `in`, which will invoke `__contains__` for you.

```
def __contains__(self, key):
    if self.root == None:
        return False
    elif key == self.root.key:
        return True
    elif key < self.root.key:
        return key in self.root.left
    else:  # key > self.root.key is the only option left
        return key in self.root.right
```

WARNING: All of the above assumes that `self.root.left` and `self.root.right` exist and are not `None`, an assumption that may not be accurate but cannot be confirmed without code showing how a `BinTree` is constructed.

Comment: Wrong. if he renames his class it wont work.  call self.contains

Comment: @LucaSansS I consider breaking inheritance to be a bigger and more likely problem than changing the name of the class. The first solution is not recommended, though I'll make an explicit note about a name change.

Answer (score 0):

If you have separate tree and node types, you want two functions, one of them recursing through the nodes and the other just to get things going.

Something like this:

```
def __contains__(self, key):
    returns self.node_contains(self.root, key)

def node_contains(self, node, key):
    if node == None:
        return False
    elif key == node.key:
        return True
    elif key < node.key:
        return self.node_contains(node.left, key)
    elif key > node.key:
        return self.node_contains(node.right, key)
```

or, you could divide the work between the classes, which could look like

In the tree class:

```
def __contains__(self, key):
    return self.root and key in self.root
```

In the node class:

```
def __contains__(self, key):
    return self.key == key 
        or (key < self.key and self.left and key in self.left) 
        or (self.right and key in self.right)
```

Answer (score -1):

Trivial fix

```
     1      def __contains__(self, key):
     2          if self.root == None:
     3              return False
     4          elif key== self.root.key:
     5              return True
     6          elif key < self.root.key:
     7              return self.__contains__(self.root.key.left,key)
     8          elif key > self.root.key:
     9              return self.__contains__(self.root.key.right,key)
```

just call `self.__contains__`

Comment: Ugh. Please *do not* use the special method of one object on another. While this works in this case, it is extremely fragile.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Still not working though.. Now it's complaining that I have too many positional arguments for method call, since __contains__(self,key) only has one positional argument. And if I add another positional argument, it starts complaining that __contians__ only takes one positional argument.